# PHP-Laravel get data from pivot table in manytomany relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I facing problem in fetching specific data from pivot table (manytomany relation). The scenario is that I want to fetch data from pivot table between two specific dates. When I use this code

```
$user_availability = $user->dates->where('date','>=' , $start_date)->where('date','<=' , $end_date)->get();

        foreach ($user_availability as $date)
        {
            echo $date->pivot->afternoon;
        }
```

It gives me following error

> Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\codehacking\app\Http\Controllers\UsersController.php on line 210 and at least 1 expected

**User Model:**

```
public function dates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Date')->withPivot('morning', 'afternoon','night','comment');
}
```

**Pivot table**

[image]

I can provide more information if you need. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: try update to `$user_availability = $user->dates()->where('date','>=' , $start_date)->where('date','<=' , $end_date)->get();`

Comment: @ab_ab surprisingly it works!

Comment: `()` makes surprises..

Comment: Thank you very much! You can post answer

Comment: I was fetching single result without `()` by using `first()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

Querying Relations

> Since all types of Eloquent relationships are defined via methods, you
>   may call those methods to obtain an instance of the relationship
>   without actually executing the relationship queries.

Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties

> If you do not need to add additional constraints to an Eloquent
>   relationship query, you may access the relationship as if it were a
>   property.

Change the query to

```
$user_availability = $user->dates()->where('date','>=' , $start_date)->where('date','<=' , $end_date)->get();
```

`parenthesis` are used in the relation `dates` to querying the relation.